# Authenticate gmail account for server side

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, oauth, google-drive-api

I need to have clients logging in to the system and uploading files. I'm developing using google app engine.

All the files should be uploaded to a centralized google drive (not individual peoples drives).

Therefore I need to authenticate clients separately and I need to authenticate server side to a separate drive account.

I have already done the client side authentication and uploading a file to my own drive using this https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js

How can I authenticate the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#ServiceAccounts).

```
import httplib2
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
driveWorker = build('drive', 'v2',http = http)
```